# Comparing completely different predictive models

Tags: regression, correlation, predictive-models

I have a list of different models to predict a chemical value called COD that is based on other parameters (lets call them P1, P2, P3,...Pn). For example:

- model 1: COD = 1.08P1 + 87*P2
- model 2: COD = 1.02228P1² + 8.7*P2 + 999.4*P5
- model 3: COD = 1.028P1$^{P4}$ + 999.4*P6 + 77*P7

Etc.  I want to get the BEST COD model possible, If I have some test data available, what metrics should I use to compare them?

I figured that mean square error makes sense, I also heard AIC makes sense since there are different amounts of parameters and different parameters, but I don't really know how to do it. Wikipedia is not very helpful and I don't know how to input just these models in R. Is there a way to do AIC manually and where would I learn that?

Also what other metrics are useful? When running the models on test data to compare how it fares on the observed data compared to the predicted data.

Comment: Where did these models come from? Were they fitted to your data or did they already exist? Do they come from some theoretical knowledge of the chemical properties? What is your goal for the final model?

Comment: They were fitted by randomizing the constants and variables and the ones with the best R-squared values is chosen to iteratively be made even better until some point where it is a finished model as a example, The goal is as I explained earlier to have some way of estimating COD values because it's time consuming and expensive to make COD measurements. But there are other relatively simple models that seem to explain it better than just linear regression (smaller mean squared error) but what other ways to check how good it is?

Comment: That sounds like a method destined to overfit. What was wrong with "just linear regression"? So far, this doesn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: There are many ways to avoid overfitting, just assume that it's not overfitted, then what. I have data to do tests on that is not part of the data used to train or validate the models.

Comment: I prefer not to "just assume that it's not overfitted", especially when it comes from a process that seems destined to overfit.

Comment: Good to know, are there any other metrics other than mean squared errors which make sense? If it is overfitted then the mean squared error should be worse than a linear regression anyway when used on new data. Right? Any other metrics that would be useful? So we can check for overfitting as well when used on new data.

Comment: There are infinitely many possible metrics. When choosing among them, what matters is how you intend to use your model.  What is the objective?

Comment: The objective is (as I have said 3 times now so I will just quote the last time) "to have some way of estimating COD values because it's time consuming and expensive to make COD measurements." so a model that can consistently get predicted COD results that are as close as possible to the observed COD results. The metrics that makes sense to me is mean squared error, mean absolute error and mean absolute percentage error.

But is there something I am missing out on?